# To make date changes with if condition in mysql

Tags: mysql

for this my query is =

```
SELECT SalesDate,COUNT(Shape) as pcs,
       ROUND(SUM(TotalAmount),2) as amount,
       ROUND(SUM(Carat),2) as carat,
       ROUND(ROUND(SUM(TotalAmount),2)/ROUND(SUM(Carat),2),2) as avgprice 
from `tbl_sales`
WHERE IF((SalesDate = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) = null, SalesDate=CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY,SalesDate= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

so this is my response

[image]

so in If condition I want to make sure that if the data in yesterday data is null or 0 then it will take day before yesterday

Comment: We need to know DDL of the table

Comment: @LordF salesDate = datetime, pcs = int , amount = double, carat = double, avgprice = double

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast your column to date:

```
SELECT SalesDate,COUNT(Shape) as pcs,
       ROUND(SUM(TotalAmount),2) as amount,
       ROUND(SUM(Carat),2) as carat,
       ROUND(ROUND(SUM(TotalAmount),2)/ROUND(SUM(Carat),2),2) as avgprice 
from `tbl_sales`
WHERE IF((CAST(SalesDate AS date) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY), CAST(SalesDate AS date) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY, CAST(SalesDate AS date) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```
SELECT SalesDate,COUNT(Shape) as pcs,
       ROUND(SUM(TotalAmount),2) as amount,
       ROUND(SUM(Carat),2) as carat,
       ROUND(ROUND(SUM(TotalAmount),2)/ROUND(SUM(Carat),2),2) as avgprice 
FROM `tbl_sales`
GROUP BY SalesDate
HAVING SalesDate = CASE WHEN (SalesDate = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)=0
                        THEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY
                        WHEN (SalesDate = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)=1
                           AND amount IS NULL
                        THEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY
                        ELSE CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY END;
```

When you do `(SalesDate = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)` it will return false=0 and true=1. Therefore doing `(SalesDate = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) = NULL`, although it should be  `.. IS NULL` instead of  `.. = NULL`.. either way, it won't work. Let's inspect the `CASE` expression in `HAVING` part.

1. If it return `0` means there's no matching with date specified, then take 2 days before:

```
CASE WHEN (SalesDate = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)=0 
                THEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY
```

2. If it has match for the date checking and return `1` BUT with `NULL` amount, then take 2 days before as well:

```
WHEN (SalesDate = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)=1  
       AND amount IS NULL
  THEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY
```

3. Else take yesterday date:

```
 ELSE CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY END;
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6d9f79c24112996b66a63eec4c9818c3)